# How to test multiple ASP.NET 5 projects in IIS without publishing?

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I like the way doing test/debug in previous versions - host the projects in IIS, rebuild, refresh and you see the changes. Attach the w3p process to VS whenever you need debug.

It seems the new ASP.NET 5 doesn't allow me to do this easily. It is tedious to publish a project to IIS to see the changes, especially with multiple projects. What is the correct way to host multiple projects in a continuously running process so it can be built and tested rapidly? Assume you have 1 MVC and 6 webapi apps communicating with each other.

Comment: I use this on a WCF web service project (which I assume you can also do on a WebApi project): Within either VS2013 or VS2015, I right-click the project, select `Debiug`, then `Start new instance`. Then you can run the MVC app as per normal (via `F5`)

Comment: @FrankFajardo, this is fine in one or two projects, but not very efficient in multiple projects.

Comment: so you want to debug 6 WebAPI apps at the same time? What were you doing before that you could not do now?

Comment: Not necessarily debug. Sometimes I just want to see the changes made to the projects. If hosted in IIS, I can rebuild the solution and see the changes directly. Now I have to use "start without debug" to push the changes to IIS express on each individual project to see the change. Also the test URL could stop working after the IIS express stopped

Comment: This might help: http://codedbeard.com/asp-net-5-0-deploy-to-local-iis/

Comment: Thanks @FrankFajardo, but it still needs a publish

Answer (score 1):

This should work, if you setup the webs in IIS manually and if yo map those webs to to the publish output folders (\artifacts\bin...\Release\PublishOutput)

**EDITED:**

If this is done, add an post build event to the project.json:

```
"scripts": {
  "postbuild": [ "dnu publish"],
  "prepublish": [ "npm install", "bower install", "gulp clean", "gulp min" ]
}
```

Maybe you need to install bower and gulp on your machine:

```
npm install -g bower
npm install -g gulp
```

If the build is done, you'll find the published output in the artifacts.

Hope this helps a little bit.

Comment: Hi Juergen, I followed your suggestion but rebuild didn't publish changes with "Produce outputs on build" checked. Also getting "file in use error " when manually publishing individual project with the app hosted under IIS.

Comment: Hi, you are right, the approach in the original answer just published the application as a NuGet package.
I played around a little bit and found a solution. I edited the post